# Is it possible to start minikube with custom virtual machine?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Minikube runs a single-node Kubernetes cluster inside a Virtual Machine (VM) on our laptop.

Wanted to check if we start minikube to use custom virtual machine?

I am trying to run minikube on Mac OS.

Comment: see this [kubernetes on mac os](https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/guide-install-kubernetes-mac.html)

Comment: when minikube start, minikube will start a virtual machine. My query was to start minikube on a custom virtual machine.

Comment: Can you elaborate it `Wanted to check if we start minikube to use custom virtual machine? `

Comment: I have created a custom virtual machine, this virtual machine includes some specific utilities. We wanted to start minikube using this custom virtual machine so that utils are available when I run, `minikiune ssh`

Comment: [Specifying the VM driver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/#specifying-the-vm-driver)

Answer (score 1):

We can start a custom image using the below option.

minikube start --iso-url=<> -p=test123 --vm-driver=hyperkit

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely.
You can make use of minikube start --vm-driver option. Document https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/03/28/running-kubernetes-locally-on-linux-with-minikube-now-with-kubernetes-1.14-support/